# Starting LanguageTool from TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, paths, grammar, java

I am trying to start *LanguageTool* grammar checker from *TexStudio* on OS X 10.10.2. This is done defining in Preferences/Grammar the path to Java. I have installed the recent **JRE8** but I don't know **how to define the path to Java** on this computer. I have been successful with this in Windows and other Mac (using simply *java* in the path).

Comment: Open the terminal and type `whereis java`.

Comment: I got `/usr/bin/java` but it seems not to solve the problem of starting *LanguageTool*. Maybe what I need is the path to `JRE` and not to java.

Comment: Check inside `/usr/lib`.

Comment: It does not work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. The path for JRE8 in OSX is: `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this configuration works fine.

[image]