# How to setup LanguageTool for TexStudio installed via HomeBrew on macOS

Tags: texstudio, mac, java

I have installed LanguageTool via HomeBrew:

```
brew install languagetool
```

which automatically installs OpenJDK as a dependency

```
brew install java
```

which places the Java binaries in `/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin` or `/usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/`

```
openjdk 13.0.2 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Also for [some reason](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/237728/how-to-add-openjdk-java-executable-to-lo-on-macos/?answer=237748#post-id-237748), I had to install the OpenJDK Cask

```
brew cask install java
```

now when running `java --version` it returns

```
openjdk 14 2020-03-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)
```

which I think is the Cask version. And when running `which java` it returns the "symlink"

```
/usr/bin/java
```

which using the `readlink` command (from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22132/167505)) returns an origin of

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Now following the [other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327650/102825) on this forum, I tried to set all of these paths in TexStudio

with no avail. I tried all three different paths mentioned above, none working. I would appreciate it if you could help me know how to set the values `Java`, `LT Path`, and `LT Arguments` in the TexStudio > `Preferences` > `Language Checking`. Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved the problem. Sorta!

So from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282571/102825), I had to run the LanguageTool GUI `/usr/local/bin/languagetool-gui` activate the port first:

then manually run the LanguageTool server on a terminal `/usr/local/bin/languagetool-server`

and then settings on TexStudio

The problem is that TexStudio does not run the LanguageTool server as it should.

**P.S.** The issue has also been described on [this page](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/2251/). TexStudio is not able to run the LanguageTool server on its own!.

Answer (score 1):

### TeXstudio 3.0, November 2020

The **solution** is easy: put the output of `which languagetool-server` to the *Language Checking > LanguageTool > Java* field.
Usually it's `/usr/local/bin/languagetool-server`.

The **problem** is that in Homebrew LT is wrapped in a shell script:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/languagetool-server
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_HOME:-/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home}"
exec "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" -cp "/usr/local/Cellar/languagetool/5.1.3_2/libexec/languagetool-server.jar" org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer "$@"
```

It means than LT shouldn't launch, say, `java languagetool.jar` but the script which already includes this command.

That's the output of *Help > Check LanguageTool*:

```
which java: /usr/local/bin/languagetool-server
JAVA: /usr/local/bin/languagetool-server
Real-time checking is enabled.
Grammar checking is enabled.
Tries to start automatically.
LT current status: working
LT-URL: http://localhost:8081/v2/check
```

Comment: What are your arguments for the fields LT path, LT arguments and server url?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/languagetool-server`, default, default

Answer (score 0):

This setting worked for me. You can copy paste the lines from the script "/usr/local/bin/languagetool-server".

[image]